# Some data has already been output TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF library for generating PDF and my code is

```
include("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

$html = "Muhammad Shoaib";

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

its working fine but when I add my `HTML` code then its giving me the error and my `HTML` code is

```
$html = '<table>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>';
                $html .= 'Test';
            $html .= '/<td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    $html .= '</table>';
```

and error is

```
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

I found several links but didn't understand the problem.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011050/tcpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146967/tcpdf-mpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-to-browser-cant-send-pdf) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665540/tcpdf-error-image-unable-to-get-image) [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060947/tcpdf-error-unable-to-get-the-size-of-the-image) [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf)

Comment: Try adding ob_clean(); and ob_start();

Comment: `ob_clean()` and `ob_end_clean()` also didn't work for me.

Comment: The main problem is my html code is not working.

Comment: Then why don't you just try to echo your html and see what's wrong? Put '$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');' in comment and add echo('html');

Comment: `html` is ok and its working now.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: my closing should be like `</td>` instead of `'/<td>';`.